# Is it a problem that I've traveled to the US unemployed, in terms of applying for other visas?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, turkish-citizens

I am currently employed and if I can get the visitor visa I will be travelling to the US in March.  I am planning to visit the UK in August as well. The potential issue is I will be unemployed in March and will be working around April or May. Do you think that UK EOC would question why I was travelling to the US as an unemployed person and how i was able to afford such a trip?

Edit: I am from Turkey

Comment: The UK ECO will only be interested in your US trip to establish that you complied with your visa restrictions there. They aren't concerned with your employment status so much as whether you can support yourself and whether you will leave the UK on time. Having a job obviously helps with both those concerns.

Comment: Why not apply for the UK visa in April, after you get back from the USA? Having a good travel record to G8 countries will work in your benefit.

Comment: @RoboKaren I will definitely apply for the UK visa in April if i will be employed then. Actually i had a UK visitor visa 1.5 years ago and not to mention schengen visas. What  worries me is a refusal from the US which presumably makes UK ECO alarmed.

Comment: VTC: whether a gap in employment might affect a US visa application or refusal that might potentially affect a future UK visa application: pure speculation... no one can predict two unknowns.